# invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 with Rails flash messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding, spree

we use Rails 3 and Spree Commerce for our online shop and we have a payment provider, that returns errors in a redirect URL if some occur. When an error occurs, we present that string with flash messages to the user.

Yesterday, something didn't work, and the payment provider returned this string in the redirect URL, which should be presented to the user inside a flash message:

```
errormsg=Bitte+versuchen+Sie+es+sp%E4ter+nochmals.
```

I debugged a little bit, and the string looks like this when decoded (e.g. is written to flash[:error]):

```
Bitte versuchen Sie es sp\xE4ter nochmals.
```

And after that, an error is raised, when rails tries to render the flash message:

```
invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

Can someone tell me, how to fix this? The error should contain a german `ä` and not `\xE4`. I tried setting `# encoding: utf-8` to the beginning of the controller and the view, but this doesn't help.

Comment: Do you have *any* control over how the payment provider generates the URL?

Comment: Yes, I can specify a redirect URL, and the provider appends the parameters. After that, I can do whatever I want with the parameters. I was thinking about forced UTF-8 encoding or sth like that. But I can't figure out, how to display the right character `ä`

Comment: Well, if you can work out which encoding the provider is using, you could decode their parameters and then re-encode them in UTF-8... (Or just not re-encode if you just need it as tetx.)

Comment: how can I find out, which encoding the provider is using? I can't find anything in the documentation. When I do `params["errormsg"].encoding` it tells me `#<Encoding:UTF-8>`.

Comment: I tried it with `params["errormsg"].encode("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-15")`, now it seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Obviously, your payment provider uses ISO-8859-1 or similar to send german umlauts.
As your rails app uses UTF-8, you can convert the message of your provicder.

Assume you stored the message in variable msg, use

```
utf_msg = params[:errormsg].force_encoding('ISO-8859-1').encode('UTF-8')
```

you can also check, if the resulting encoding is valid:

```
uft_msg.valid_encoding?
```

and outpunt a different message to avoid errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just commented on my original post. Is there a difference between `force_encoding` and the method I've used? And whats the difference between `ISO-8859-1` and `ISO-8859-15`?

Comment: putting the comment `# -*- encoding : UTF-8 -*-` in a controller sets the character encoding for the **source code**, allowing you to use umlauts in string literals (i.e. `notice: 'gelöscht'`). It has no affect on your string variables. Each variable can have a different encoding. See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html

Comment: the difference between `ISO-8859-1` and `ISO-8859-1` are verry little. i.e. `ISO-8859-15` defines the euro character `€`.